# PHP money_format not working

Tags: php

I'm using Laravel 4 on TurnkeyLinux and trying to get [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) to display currency in a localized manner.

`money_format('%.2n', 1222002.09)` returns 1222002.09.

In app/strart/global.php I have `App::setLocale(Session::get('locale', 'en'));`, this alters the language using Laravel's language files but has no effect on currency.

I've discovered that `localeconv();` outputs a nearly empty array (only decimal point is set) and using `setLocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB', 'en_GB');` has no effect.

I'm on PHP 5.4.4 and Debian 3.2.57.

Comment: Perhaps you need to do a `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root to enable the correct locale details on your server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it! Thanks to Dmitry Bezik for pointing me in the right direction.

`locale -a` returned:

- C
- C.UTF-8
- POSIX

The lack of GB (or US) locales prompted me to do another search that found 
me [this page](https://people.debian.org/~schultmc/locales.html).

Basically I hadn't got any locales installed, so I followed the instructions and installed the GB locale by doing the following:

1. Opened /etc/locale.gen using WinSCP and scrolled down the list of commented-out locales until I found `en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8` and removed the leading "#", (if your file is empty, just adding an entry should work).
2. Ran `/usr/sbin/locale-gen` as root, this made the system "Generate locales" (which only took a second).
3. Added `setLocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.utf8', 'en_GB');` to my blade template and refreshed.

Voilà! I now get `£1,222,002.09`.
I then moved my `setLocale` code into my app/start/global.php just after I set the language so it run on every request.

Comment: On my debian, I used these commands: `apt-get install locales` and `
apt-get install locales-all` to install all the locales, not just a specific one.