# PHP setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US') not working as expected

Tags: php, formatting

I execute the following code:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US')  
echo money_format('%(!n', 1000)
```

I expected to get `1,000.00`, but instead I get `1000.00`.

What do I do wrong that there is no comma?

Comment: Take a look: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398923/php-money-format-not-working)

Comment: I got  `1,000.00`  refer @AHJeebon's link

Answer (score 4):

Please try `locale -a` in your terminal.

In my case, I found that I had `en_US.utf8` and not `en_US` installed.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.utf8');
```

It may be a good idea to use something like DOTENV to load the correct locale settings on whatever machine you run the code:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, env('LOCALE', 'en_US.utf8'));
```

With a `.env` file containing a `LOCALE` entry:

```
LOCALE=en_US
```

Comment: When I go with 'en_US.utf8' it indeed adds the comma, but it also shoves in a USD ... alas, I think I'll have to just number format like below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use **[number-format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)**

```
$num =  1000;
echo number_format($num,2,".",""); // 1000.00
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/U2AEE)**

Comment: There is no comma in your demo as well. But I think this is the more reliable way for my simple approach than the comments above