# Why money_format() PHP function does not format the numbers?

Tags: php, locale, money-format

I want to format numbers according to the desired locale setting. So, I am using the example code from the PHP manual:

```
$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56
```

Instead of the expected result, I just get the unformatted value "1234.56". The same happens if I use a different locale, for example 'it_IT' instead of 'en_US'.

Why doesn't if format?

Comment: Refor to [PHP money_format not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25398923/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

For there is no `en_US` locals in your envs. USe `locale -a` to check it.

You've to install it. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25399672/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual tells that the `money_format( string $format , float $number )` function relies on the `strfmon()` C-function.

The possible options you can pass as the `$format` argument are the ones that the `locale` command of your operating system can understand. If you pass something different then the number is not formatted at all, it is just converted to string. This is what has happened to me.

In order to list the accepted values, you can use this command from the prompt:

```
locale -a
```

Depending on your installation, it may list only a couple of locales. In order to use more, you may want to install other locales. In Debian you can do it this way:

```
apt-get install locales
apt-get install locales-all
```

After installing all the locales, the `locale -a` command lists hundreds of locales. Now the `number_format()` function works as you expected.